# RewriteRule to match anything alphanumeric or dash only

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a rule that matches domain.com/abc

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ results.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
```

This works and category=abc but this rule also seems to be triggered if I just go to domain.com

I need my rule to only match if the URL after the slash contains alphanumeric characters or a dash. It can not match a forward slash as domain.com/abc/123 would not be valid.

```
domain.com/abc123 is good
domain.com/abc-123 is good
domain.com/abc/123 should not match
domain.com should not match
domain.com/ should not match
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ results.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

To avoid matching underscore use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ results.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To safeguard it use this condition to avoid matching directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ results.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```